# keras installation error: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use keras.models. Here is the code I have in a python script

```
import keras.models
```

Running it gives me this error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keras.models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling keras as well as installing keras.models seperately however in both cases I still get this error. Why is this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your Tensorflow, re-install that.

Comment: Try to change its version.